# mpi p2p send receive communication between c and c++ codes

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, mpi, communication

Does one need to do anything special when communicating between two code parts/function where the sources are written in different languages (C and C++)?

I have injected into C++ code the send that are used by all parallel slave tasks with different ranks:

```
if (rank != 0)
{
    const long bufferlength = 1000000; 
    char filename[300];
    double array[bufferlength*4];

    MPI_Send(filename, 300, MPI_CHAR, 0, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
    MPI_Send(array, bufferlength*4, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
}
```

In C source the corresponding receive is placed and called by master 0 process only, as many times as slave tasks exist (here `num_process`):

```
if (rank==0)
{
    typedef struct array_s
    {
        char filename[300];//text for file name as identifier
        double *t;//time buffer 
        double *x;//X coordinate buffer
        double *y;//Y coordinate buffer
        double *z;//Z coordinate buffer
    } arraystruc;
    arraystruc arraybuffer;

    double array[bufferlength*4]; 

    for(i=1;i<num_process;i++) 
    {
        MPI_Recv(arraybuffer.filename, 300, MPI_CHAR, i, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);    
        MPI_Recv(array, bufferlength*4, MPI_DOUBLE, i, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
    }
}
```

The character array is arriving correctly, but unfortunatly the array buffer is not arriving at master correctly. It is simply empty.

Comment: `1000000 * 4 * 8` bytes, maybe it's too big for the stack

Comment: what is `if (rank<>0)` supposed to do?

Comment: Are you sure that `bufferlength` is the same in both places?

Comment: Thansk wesley, that seems was the bug. 
I didn't mention, that using different size for arrays when sending and receiving...

Comment: Seems also the Buffer size is the reason as of by default many MPI implementations have 2-4MB for MPI-Buffer communication and here I were tryting to use 10 times bigger buffer...